# É possível diminuir o tempo de inicialização da minha aplicação?

Tags: java, swing, thread

Já vi muita coisa aqui e no StackOverflow em inglês sobre Swing e `Runnable`, mesmo assim não consegui resolver meu problema.

Estou desenvolvendo um trabalho para a faculdade (trabalho interdisciplinar, envolvendo Sistemas Distribuídos/Estruturas de Dados Avançadas/Tecnologia e Educação), que consiste em um jogo de Palavras Cruzadas. O problema é que o usuário terá a possibilidade de "montar" a Palavra Cruzada.

Ou seja, a partir de uma janela secundária, ele informará quantas linhas e colunas a Palavra Cruzada possuirá. A quantidade mínima será de 10 linhas por 10 colunas. Como vocês devem já ter adivinhado, ao fechar o formulário e chamar o método que constrói a interface (matriz de `JTextField`) na janela principal, há um tempo aproximado de 8 segundos até que a janela se "descongele". E o tempo fica maior à medida que a "grade" também cresce. Como parâmetro: Para a construção de uma grade de 15 X 15, a matriz aparece em aproximadamente 1 segundo. Porém, demora 18 segundos para "descongelar".

Será que há uma solução para esse problema?

Comment: Para possibilitar que os outros possam te ajudar, tente compartilhar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o EDT.

O *event dispatching thread* (EDT) é uma thread Java para processar eventos do Abstract Window Toolkit (AWT), ele coloca em fila os eventos vindos da interface para tratar paralelamente. É um clássico exemplo do conceito de programação orientada a eventos, que é popular em muitos outros contextos, por exemplo, navegadores web ou servidores web.

Ele implementa o *worker design pattern* para fazer esse tratamento paralelo da interface e assim conseguir tratar múltiplas tarefas.

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  new Thread(new Runnable()
  {
    final String text = readHugeFile();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
      public void run()
      {
        textArea.setText(text);
      }
    });
  }).start();
}
```

Veja o exemplo, ele utiliza a classe `SwingUtilities` que invoca uma nova thread para setar o `text`. Esse tipo de *approach* pode ser a solução para o seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar **user34038**. Eu já havia tentado do jeito que você colocou e infelizmente não melhorou o desempenho. Mesmo assim eu agradeço. Valeu.